# AFNetworking, upload simple NSData with POST

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I created an NSDictionary containing arrays and strings and other client info, using setObject forKey. Everything looks great when I NSLog the data, format is exactly the way its supposed be. I've also converted my NSDictionary to NSData:

```
NSData *userData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

What I need to know is how to upload it to the server using POST. I've found the following code snippet to upload a photo. My question is can I simply use my NSDictionary as a parameter (params in request), it's kinda big. If not, how do I send my NSData object userData? I really love AFNetworking and have been using it exclusively for all my download needs. This is my first time uploading an object.
Thanks

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pageImage);

AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.SERVER.com"]];


//You can add POST parameteres here
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    author, @"author",
                    title, @"title",
                    nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/PATH/TO/WEBSERVICE.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

//This is the image
[formData appendPartWithFileData: imageData name:@"cover_image" fileName:@"temp.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];


}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

//Setup Upload block to return progress of file upload
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten,     long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
NSLog(@"Upload Percentage: %f %%", progress*100);
}];




//Setup Completeion block to return successful or failure
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id     responseObject) {
NSString *response = [operation responseString];
NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
//Code to run after webservice returns success response code

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
    //Code to Run if Failed

}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand you question, but I will give it a try anyway.

> My question is can I simply use my NSDictionary as a parameter (params in request), it's kinda big.

I think so. Just give it a try... in the end, those array will be converted in data sent to the server, so if the server is able to handle it, there should be no problem.

> If not, how do I send my NSData object userData?

The data you send should be provided where the code you posted specifies `imageData`. Keep in mind that if what you are uploading is not meant to be a file (you mention NSData), then you might need to use `appendPartWithFormData:name`. This, again, depends on your server side.

Hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Thank you!!! Need to fix some bugs on the server but it works like a charm on my end. Love AFNetworking!!!